# how to get url parameter in AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible to get the url parameter to use inside an amp page?

Say my page is 
*www.mydomain.com/index.amp.html*

and I want to pass a parameter to that page like this
*www.mydomain.com/index.amp.html?**someparameter=myvalue***

and I want to use it like this **{{ someparameter }}** to display/get the value **"myvalue"**

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1299), this feature will work in non-viewer scenarios but not inside the viewer. Here's a code snippet from this [link](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/1746):

```
this.set_('QUERY_STRING', (param, defaultValue = "") => {
      assert(param, 'The first argument to QUERY_STRING, the query string ' +  /*OK*/'param is required');
      const url = parseUrl(this.win_.location.href);
      const params = parseQueryString(url.search);

      return (typeof params[param] !== "undefined") ?
```